# Sufficient conditions for the weight function to have compact embedding of a weighted Sobolev space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $\rho$ be a smooth density function on $\mathbb{R}^N$, that is, $\rho(x)\ge 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^N$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\rho(x) dx=1$. Let $L^p_\rho(\mathbb{R}^N)=\{f: \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} |f|^p d\rho<\infty\}$, and $W^{p,k}_\rho(\mathbb{R}^N)=\{f\in L^p_\rho(\mathbb{R}^N): D^\alpha f\in L^p_\rho(\mathbb{R}^N) \}$ for all $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\ldots, \alpha_n)\in\mathbb{N}_0^n$ with $\alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_n=k$. What are the sufficient conditions for $\rho$ to conclude that the embedding
$$ W^{p,k}_\rho(\mathbb{R}^N)\hookrightarrow L^p_\rho(\mathbb{R}^N) $$ is compact?

I have looked for such a result on the internet but could not find an appropriate reference. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can have a look at Chapter 8 of the book "Analytic methods for Markov semigroups" by M. Bertoldi and L. Lorenzi.

Comment: Thanks for the reference.